# Custom landing page for SaaS application

Tags: css, html, saas, branding

I am building a SaaS based web application, to which users can connect using their own domain and apply their company branding to it.

How can I customize the landing page of my application based on domain from which it is being accessed. There is no login information to identify the customer.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "domain from which it is being accessed"? The users IP Address or the last Page the user has in his browser history? Hint: Both are not really useful to display a customized Landing Page.

Comment: @MatthiasS. I meant the URL can be different i.e. www.site1.com for one customer and www.site2.com for another. But they would be connecting to my server. So customers can point there own web domains to our servers and server will render their our UI with their branding.

Comment: Is there any authentication required to access your app? If there isn't how do you determine who is allowed to access it?

Comment: Its the landing page, so there is no authentication required. It's a SaaS application so customers can customize it and apply their branding. Each customer is given unique URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your landing page, you can fetch request url and then customize the response accordingly.

You didn't mention the programming language, however in Java we can use ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURL().toString() to get it.

Recently for one of my projects I used a third party service -  [www.grooveui.com](https://www.grooveui.com), it does something similar but without you having to write server side code.

Comment: Thanks. I found this grooveui.com promising.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put in your iframe such code:

```
<script>
    var wantedUrl = (window.location != window.parent.location)
                    ? document.referrer
                    : document.location.href;
    var wantedUrlEsc = escape(wantedUrl);
    var newEl = document.createElement('script');
    newEl.src = "https://your.server.com?wantedUrlEsc=" + wantedUrlEsc;

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newEl);
    // or document.head.appendChild(newEl) in modern browsers
</script>
```

and on server side you can try read and decode the `wantedUrlEsc` parameter.

Good luck!